# Can't connect to wireless on Lubuntu

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, blacklist

I have a Cisco PCI LAN+WLAN 802.11b card in my IBM ThinkPad T30 laptop.

Is this wireless card compatible with Lubuntu?

I have Lubuntu installed and it just won't connect. It keeps saying that it is trying to configure then it says that it is connected but it does not work.

I know that the wireless network is working correctly because I can connect to it with all my other devices and it works on this very same laptop when I am running Windows.

I added the following commands to blacklist.conf, but still no luck

```
blacklist padlock_aes
blacklist geode_aes
```

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting with a **Zydas WLAN USB 2.0  Adapter** [here](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Technologies-802-11g-Wireless-Network-Adapter/dp/B000CC3ZFS/ref=sr_1_40?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1342652847&sr=1-40).

It works for me, it cost £6.95 from Amazon.

Comment: Buying new hardware is rarely the answer. I'm going to try researching this.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu (and all derivatives) should have a built-in driver for Aironet cards (as per [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man4/airo.4.html)). First off, try blacklisting airo_cs (It's for PCMCIA cards only) and rebooting. If that doesn't work, read below.

Also see [this page](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/airo) which says that the Aironet card does not support 802.11g/n or WPA2.

I also read somewhere that the airo driver makes a shadow of wlan0 as eth1. Try doing `sudo ifup eth1` and see if that enables your wireless.

From information I found on the [Lenovo site](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?&LegacyDocID=MIGR-51424) it seems that you have to install the Cisco Aironet Client Utilities (ACU). [Here is a link](http://tools.cisco.com/search/JSP/search-results.get?strQueryText=Linux%20ACU&Search%20All%20Cisco.com=cisco.com) to the search results that will get you where you want to go. You'll need to register for an account to download it though.